# OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:109 : Not found: ; No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

https://github.com/caicloud/tensorflow-tutorial/blob/master/Deep_Learning_with_TensorFlow/1.4.0/Chapter12/5.%20%E5%90%8C%E6%AD%A5%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E6%A8%A1%E5%BC%8F%E6%A0%B7%E4%BE%8B%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F.py

What is the problem with the program running failures on two different machines and running on one machine?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free debugging service. And please post the code directly here on SO.